# when checkout a previous commit, Is there a quick way to input the log commit hash?

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh

It's really tedious to type the following command:

```
git checkout 622fe0a9b6bffdf4723026ae6e673245b510ac66
```

Is there autocomplete or shortcut to do this?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I'm using `oh my zsh!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you have a *ton* of shortcuts which avoid entering the SHA1 altogether.

The short SHA1 are mentioned in "[Git Tools - Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)", but [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) section on "[SPECIFYING REVISIONS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions)" mentions also (small extract):

- `master@{5}`: the 5th prior value of master
- `master~3` A suffix `~<n>` to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>`th generation ancestor of the named commit object
- `:/fix nasty bug` names a commit whose commit message matches the specified regular expression
- `master@{yesterday}`, `HEAD@{5 minutes ago}`:  specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time.
- ... and so on.

So if you known when or where you old commit is based on the current branch, for instance, you have other options.

Comment: +1. I'd recommend that you get familiar with the treeishes VonC has linked to in his answer. They're much more effective than partial or complete SHAs.

Answer (score 5):

If you only enter the first few characters, it'll work as long as it's unambiguous.

Comment: Copy/paste seems to be the fastest way ;) But yes, you can just type in the first X characters until you have specified an unambiguous commit ID. I've never had to enter more than 6 characters.